# Concatenar los valores de una columna en una variable string

Tags: c#, sql, lista, datagridview

estoy seguro que lo que deseo es sencillo. Necesito concatenar todos los valores de la columna "Nombre" de mi datagridview llamado "dgvProcedimientos" en una variable. Hice algo similar con un listbox de esta forma:

```
StringBuilder procedimientos = new StringBuilder();
                procedimientos.Clear();

                foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)

                {
                    procedimientos.Append(item);
                    procedimientos.Append("----");
                }
```

pero no se como hacer eso mismo con un datagridview.

Comment: Es decir, si en la columna Nombre está David, Pepe, Jose, quieres presentar la unión de los nombres (David, Pepe y Jose). Eso es lo que quieres hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes usar el mismo código que tienes, sustituyes el listbox y lo dejas como grid, y en item accedes a la celda en la columna deseada y listo:

```
        StringBuilder procedimientos = new StringBuilder();
        procedimientos.Clear();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvProcedimientos.Rows)

        {
            procedimientos.Append(item.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString());
            procedimientos.Append("----");
        }
```

También puedes usar linq:

```
        string nombres =string.Join("---",dgvProcedimientos.Rows
                .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                .Select(r => r.Cells["Nombre"].Value.ToString()));
```

Comment: excelente. muchas gracias. solo que al final de la ultima palabra salen los --- hay alguna forma de que no los coloque si no hay una palabra por el medio